# Remove uiimageview from view

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift2

I have a feed and i am wanting to display images if the user does not have an image, it will say null in the json. if the user does have a image, the image will be set with the image url.

i want to remove it so it will not take up space in the tableview cell.

my code is:

```
if imageStringFromJson == nil {
    //how do i remove the imageview? <-- need help here
} else {
    //set image from url in imageview
}
```

Comment: `imageView.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: @DanielKrom I already tried that. i get this: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the line where it sets the image from url

Comment: ok so post more code or be more specific, question is **Remove uiimageview from view** and this is the answer

Comment: @johnjay22113 change `=` to `==`. If you compiled your code this way, some problems may occur.

Comment: @DanielKrom ok sorry i want to remove it so it will not take up space in the tableview cell.

Comment: @johnjay22113 no problem show us more code, what is the table, how does a cell looks like, there are too many options to guess :)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Or:

```
imageView.hidden = true
```

Or animate:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {    
    imageView.alpha = 0
}
```

To animate back to showing, try this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {    
    imageView.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: okay, i used the animate one and it see it disappearing. when i scroll back to a cell that has an image, the image does not show

Comment: That is because the imageView is hidden. Check my edited answer.